# Applying Fourier transform to $f(x)-\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x-t)f(t)dt=g(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-equations

**Notes**:

> $f(x)-\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x-t)f(t)dt=g(x)$ where $f,g,k\in L_1{\mathbb{R}}$ therefore the equation is solvable with a unique solution iff $1-\hat{K(\xi)}\neq 0\:\:,\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R}$.

Applying the Fourier transform to both sides of the equation:

$\hat{f}(\xi)-\hat{K}(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)=\hat{g}(\xi)\implies \hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{\hat{g}(\xi)}{1-\hat{k}(\xi)}$

**Fourier transform:**$\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{it\xi}dt\:\:,\:\: \xi\in\mathbb{R}$

**Question:**

Considering $\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x-t)f(t)$. Why did the integral disappeared when applying the Fourier transform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the convolution theorem.  Convolution becomes multiplication in the Fourier domain.

Comment: I believe you are missing a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: There are now two integrals, one for $\hat{K}$ and one for $\hat{f}$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts            Exactly I have already found that out! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x-t)f(t)dt=(K\ast f)(x),
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
(K\ast f)^{\wedge}(\xi)=\widehat{K}(\xi)\widehat{f}(\xi)
\end{align*}
for $K,f\in L^{1}({\bf{R}})$.

Comment: I know this convolution property. What strikes me is that the author applies it to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ at the same time. Does this not alter the equation? I mean the equality. Does the equality hold?

Comment: That is just the linearity of Fourier transform, no?

Comment: I am stuck with this simple example in my mind. If I have the equation $ax-by=cz$ I cannot multiply $ax$ and $cz$ for a different number and then multiply $by$ by another($a,b,c$ are scalars). This is what is confusing me on the integral equation the asymmetry in transformation between the elements.

Comment: I think you have made it too complicated. A similar example to the technique of the integral equations is like, if you have $A(x)=B(x)$, you can make $\dfrac{d}{dx}(A(x))=\dfrac{d}{dx}(B(x))$. In the case of your question, you can make $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A(t)e^{-it\xi}dt=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}B(t)e^{-it\xi}dt$, and the notation becomes $\widehat{A}(\xi)=\widehat{B}(\xi)$.

Comment: Yes your example is true. The problem is that in the equation $f(x)-\int_\limits{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x-t)f(t)=g(x)$, the $f(x)$ gets to $\hat{f(\xi)}$ as does the expression inside the integral such as $f(x)$ inside the integral. This sends me back to my prior argument with the equation $ax-by=cz$. Thanks for the effort insofar!

Comment: Actually I don't understand what is the so called $ax$ in your example?

Comment: $x,y,z$ are varaibles of the equation and $a,b,c$ are scalars. The equation is just an example it has nothing to do with the original integral equation. It is just way I found to convey my idea.

Comment: The point is that, there is only one variable in your question, it is $x$, no $y$ nor $z$.

Comment: Got it! Sorry for bothering!